# How to get focus on Material UI Link(without using component="button") using keyboard tab key

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I don't understand how to get focus on Material UI Link using Tab key in keyboard. I am placing Link inside a Button to get the job done. But is there any way to achieve my need using only Link. I'm dropping the codesandbox link for full details. Thanks in advance.

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4evbh?file=/demo.tsx

Code from sandbox:

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, createStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "& > * + *": {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2)
      }
    }
  })
);

export default function Links() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setState(!state);
  };

  return (
    <Typography className={classes.root}>
      <Link onClick={handleClick}>Link</Link>
      <Typography>Click on above link to display hidden content..</Typography>
      {state ? "" : "focus on Link using Tab key?"}
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting to use `component="button"`?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I am using NVDA screen reader. When I use component="button", screen reader is displaying and reading the Link as button. I tried to use aria-label in Link but it didn't solve the issue. Is there any way to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: It is not appropriate for the screen reader to read this as a "link" if it doesn't have an `href`. When a screen reader tells someone that they are on a link, that lets them know that certain actions are available such as opening the link in a new tab or window. These actions aren't possible on an element that just has an `onClick` handler without any href. You have decided to make this element **look** like a link, but the screen reader doesn't care what it looks like -- it's still just a button.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Accessibility portion](https://material-ui.com/components/links/#accessibility) of the `Link` documentation:

> If a link doesn't have a meaningful href, it should be rendered using a `<button>` element.

The example in the documentation is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

export default function ButtonLink() {
  return (
    <Link
      component="button"
      variant="body2"
      onClick={() => {
        console.info("I'm a button.");
      }}
    >
      Button Link
    </Link>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

When you don't specify `component="button"`, the default component for `Link` will be an `<a>` tag, but an `<a>` tag without an `href` attribute does not receive keyboard focus.

Comment: We have a file upload feature in our project. For that we used an <input type="file" id="icon-button-file" /> and the label is <label htmlFor="icon-button-file"><Link>upload</Link></label>. Here basically the upload option displays in a dialog box. When I use component="button" in the Link tag, dialog box is automatically closing without uploading the image.

Comment: @GowthamManthena If you add `type="button"` (in addition to `component="button"`), does it fix the issue?

Comment: Nope. I added type="button" in addition to component="button". But it didnt worked.

Answer (score 1):

use the global [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute

```
<Typography className={classes.root}>
  <Link onClick={handleClick} tabIndex={0}>
    Link
  </Link>
  <Typography>Click on above link to display hidden content..</Typography>
  {state ? "" : "focus on Link using Tab key?"}
</Typography>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But I got three links in the same page. I am using WAVE evaluation tool which is a chrome extension. When I give three different tabIndex values to Links WAVE tool showing a warning that is 'a positive tabindex value is present'. Is it a right approach to give tabIndex value as zero for all Links in the same page?

Comment: Yes, please take a minute to consult the documentation I linked. Assigning values greater than 0 should be avoided. Also do consider the arguably better answer [provided below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65704988/11247175)